# Removing NA's using filter function on few columns of the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large data frame that has NA's at different point. I need to remove few rows that has more NA values.

I applied `filter` using `is.na()` conditions to remove them. However, they are not yielding fruitful results.

```
S.No    MediaName KeyPress     KPIndex  Type            Secs    X       Y
001     Dat       NA           1        Fixation        18      117     89
002     New       NA           NA       Saccade         33      NA      NA
003     Dat       NA           2        Fixation        23      117     NA
```

### my code

```
df <- df%>%filter(df, !is.na(KeyPress) & !is.na(KPIndex) & !is.na(X) & !is.na(Y))
```

I would want delete based on the conditions using dplyr. I have more rows similar to this in a large dataframe. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: There are data frames in different languages, maybe give a little more context.

Comment: I think the only problem with your code is that you both pipe in `df` *and* put it as the first argument. Try removing `df, ` from inside `filter()` and just rely on the pipe. (Or vice versa.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are more than one column, use `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)     
df %>%
   filter_at(vars(KeyPress, KPIndex, X, Y), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

---

Or with `rowSums` from `base R`

```
nm1 <- c("KeyPress", "KPIndex", "X", "Y")
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[nm1]))!= 0,]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(S.No = 1:3, MediaName = c("Dat", "New", "Dat"), 
    KeyPress = c(NA, NA, NA), KPIndex = c(1L, NA, 2L), Type = c("Fixation", 
    "Saccade", "Fixation"), Secs = c(18L, 33L, 23L), X = c(117L, 
    NA, 117L), Y = c(89L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `|` instead of `&`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(KeyPress) | !is.na(KPIndex) | !is.na(X) | !is.na(Y))
```

```r
#   S.No MediaName KeyPress KPIndex     Type Secs   X  Y
# 1    1       Dat       NA       1 Fixation   18 117 89
# 2    3       Dat       NA       2 Fixation   23 117 NA
```

Comment: This one uses OR condition operator. However, I want to use and condition. Your solution works for the data given here. But I could not apply to the large dataframe that I have.

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan this is equivalent of accepted answer.

Comment: Since, I am a novice user. I think, I not able to understand the equivalence of the code. I definitely appreciate your help on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put my bid in for the simplest. Dplyr's drop_na will drop all rows that contain an NA.

```
data %>% drop_na()
```

You can specify which columns you want it to look at (or not with "-"), if that is relevant to your case.